# Import csv/xlsx file into python as a list and find a template match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have two simplified csv files below (uploaded as images and link in google drive) and I would like to ask how can I import both files in a python list format where I can iterate over the "templates.csv" and find the best match (if no perfect match exist).

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dOv-8fQgeGEsaPMXYU8kbo2mY4B2KkDH?usp=sharing

test.csv = [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeSTy.png)

templates.csv = [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyP8l.png)

My current issue is how can I import the csv files in such a way that it will be read as a list where:
**test.csv file** becomes:

test = ['AC_CURRENT', 'AC_POWER', 'AC_POWER.MAX', 'DC_CURRENT', 'DC_VOLTAGE', ....]

**templates.csv file** becomes a list of templates:

template1 = ['AC_CURRENT', 'AC_CURRENT_15MIN', 'AC_CURRENT_A', 'AC_CURRENT_B', 'AC_CURRENT_C',...]

template2 = ['AC_CURRENT', 'AC_POWER', 'AC_POWER.MAX', 'DC_CURRENT', 'DC_VOLTAGE', ....]

template3 = ['AC_CURRENT', 'AC_POWER', 'AC_POWER.MAX', 'AC_VOLTAGE', 'DC_CURRENT', ....]

templateN = ....

The first issue I have is reading both files as a dataframe where it will be converted as a list above then I can perform the iteration, finding a good match, and if no perfect match exists, it will give me a recommendation in percentage which template gives the most attributes match and will also list the missing attributes from my test.csv file that didnt have any match.

Take note that I cannot manipulate the excel file above in a easy format to pull as a list as we natively pull this from a software where these templates sits.

Thanks a lot for the help

I only have this line of codes for now which just reads the files as dataframe using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',')
df2 = pd.read_csv('templates.csv', sep=',')
print(df1)
print(df2)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXdwK.png)

Comment: Images are not going to help, can you share the csv here please

Comment: Could you give examples of your input formats as code instead of images?

Comment: Hi everyone here are the files https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dOv-8fQgeGEsaPMXYU8kbo2mY4B2KkDH?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take this example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Parent": ["x", "x", "y", "y", "z"], "Name": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
>   Parent  Name
  0      x     1
  1      x     2
  2      y     3
  3      y     4
  4      z     5

# group by 'Parent', aggregate group values to lists for each column, then get column 'Name'
grouped_as_series = df.groupby('Parent').agg(list)['Name']
> Parent
  x    [1, 2]
  y    [3, 4]
  z       [5]

# to access single values
print(grouped_as_series["x"])
> [1, 2]
```

So for your case:

```
test = df1.groupyby('Parent').agg(list)['Name']['test']
series_of_templates = df2.groupyby('Parent').agg(list)['Name']
```

Note that I'm not sure if I understand what you plan to do with the data afterwards so a series might not be the best way to store the extracted data. E.g. a dictionary or list might be better.

##### Edit:

If I understand it correctly you want to then check the percentage of match between the test list and each template:

```
test = [6, 4]

best_template_percent = 0.0
best_template_index = -1
for ind, val in grouped_as_series.items():
    match_percent = len([v for v in test if v in val])/len(test)
    if match_percent > best_template_percent:
        best_template_percent = match_percent
        best_template_index = ind

print(best_template_index)
> y
print(grouped_as_series[best_template_index])
> [3, 4]
```

Or if you want it shorter:

```
import numpy as np

best_template_index = grouped_as_series.index[np.argmax([len([v for v in test if v in val])/len(test) for ind, val in grouped_as_series.items()])]
```

For your data:

```
import numpy as np

best_template_index = series_of_templates.index[np.argmax([len([v for v in test if v in val])/len(test) for ind, val in series_of_templates.items()])]
best_template_values = series_of_templates[best_template_index]
```

Comment: Hi @ewz93 thanks a lot. It is working for my initial requirement of putting the csv file in an python list. What I plan to do with the data afterwards is to find a matching template from the first file to the second file. What I did is to use a set to make the comparison and I think I need to iterate over and over again using a for loop to find the perfect match or approximate match? It will spit out the matching tags and the unmatching tags and give me a percentage of which template gives the best match.

Comment: Hi @ewz93, I made it work but my solution is to find the perfect match. Do you have an idea how can I spit out the name of the series_of_templates including its list of items?

Comment: Check my edit. By name you probably mean the index of the series, right? Note that it might behave strangely if values can occur multiple times because it just checks for presence. Also order is ignored. Let me know if order and multiple occurences should matter for the matching then this needs to be adjusted.

Comment: Thanks @ewz93. Working as expected! I just added some tweak for the code to spit out the percentage match and the non-matching tags using set difference.